# browser-sync doesn't refresh the browser when working with python flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, gulp, browser-sync

I'm building a flask project with gulp and browser-sync to help me deal with the front-end stuff. But when I modify some files in my Flask project, the browser isn't reloaded automatically, I have to hit `F5` to refresh the browser manually in order to see the changes. Though I can see the following output from browser-sync when some changes are made:

```
[BS] Reloading Browsers...
```

This is my `gulpfile.js`, I started `browser-sync` and other gulp tasks by running `gulp` in the terminal

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var reload = browserSync.reload;
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var paths = {
    scss: ['scss/*.scss'],
    css:  ['static/css/*.css', '!static/css/*.min.css']
};

gulp.task('scss', function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.scss)
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('static/css'));
});
gulp.task('minify-css', ['scss'], function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.css)
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(cleanCSS({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('static/css'))
    .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

//Run Flask server
gulp.task('runserver', function() {
    var proc = exec('python app.py');
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', ['runserver'], function () {
  browserSync({
    notify: false,
    proxy: "127.0.0.1:5000"
  });
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch(paths.scss, ['minify-css']);
    gulp.watch(["templates/**/*.html", "static/**/*.js"]).on('change', reload);
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch', 'browser-sync']);
```

#### Edit

The directory structure is like this:

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── app.py
├── config.py
├── database.py
├── gulpfile.js
├── res
├── routes
│   ├── definitions.py
│   ├── index.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── users.py
│   └── utilities.py
├── scss
│   ├── main.scss
│   └── pushmenu.scss
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── main.css
│   │   ├── main.min.css
│   │   ├── pushmenu.css
│   │   └── pushmenu.min.css
│   ├── images
│   └── js
│       └── search.js
└── templates
    ├── index.html
    └── layout.html
```

Comment: @rick I've been confused for days, and haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Have you tried my update?

Comment: outside the last update I made I don't know how to help you. btw have you tried it?

Comment: @rick Thank you for your help. After I made some changes, browser-sync finally worked. I guess it has something to do with the `gulp.watch` part. But what confused me was that browser-sync didn't work at first even if I added all the possible files in it. Maybe it was because I was sleepy last night and something went wrong during the process. But anyway it works now. I really appreciate your help. :)

Comment: Glad you made it work! if you have time, create a little update section in your post with the uptated gulpfile.js for feature memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually you're only watching for changes for html and js files in the static and templates directory.

You can watch all the directories you want by addinthose direcotries to your watch

```
gulp.watch(["templates/**/*.html","static/**/*.js","myflaskdir/**/*.*"]).on('change', reload);
```

where "myflaskdir" is your flask dir directories.

Send a printscreen of your project directory structure so I can help you in detail.

Hope this helps

**UPDATE**
Retry is not the base dir so it must be something with the watches.Have you tried browserSync.reload() instead of just reload?

```
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch(paths.scss, ['minify-css']);
    gulp.watch(["templates/**/*.html", "static/**/*.js"]).on('change', browserSync.reload);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, you can see the directory structure in my updated question. It still doesn't work. No matter the file I'm editing is `html`, `scss`, or `js`, `browser-sync` will not reload the browser, but I guess it has detected the changes, because each time the file got modified, `browser-sync` always output a line `[BS] Reloading Browsers...`, seemed like it was trying to reload the browser.

Comment: ok, it could be something about the base dir, give me a minute and I modify my answer

Comment: Thank you for the update, sorry I didn't notice it before. But this still didn't work, I got an error: `Invalid config. You cannot specify both server & proxy options.`

Comment: ok, you need that proxy? or you need just to put browsersync on another port?

Comment: The `html` files in the `templates` directory are not pure htmls, they are `jinja2` templates, so they cannot be rendered properly without the proxy. So I need that proxy to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

As @rick pointed out, I need to add all the files in `gulp.watch` part so `browser-sync` could detect it. This is the `gulpfile.js` that works for me. I pasted it in here in hope that it could help someone.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var reload = browserSync.reload;
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var paths = {
    scss: ['scss/*.scss'],
    css:  ['static/css/*.css', '!static/css/*.min.css']
};

gulp.task('scss', function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.scss)
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('static/css'));
});
gulp.task('minify-css', ['scss'], function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.css)
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(cleanCSS({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('static/css'))
    .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

//Run Flask server
gulp.task('runserver', function() {
    var proc = exec('python app.py');
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', ['runserver'], function () {
  browserSync({
    notify: false,
    proxy: "127.0.0.1:5000",
  });
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch(paths.scss, ['minify-css']);
    gulp.watch(["templates/**/*.html", "static/**/*.js", "scss/**/*.scss"]).on('change', reload);
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch', 'browser-sync']);
```